# Как получить url картинок с сайта?

Tags: python, requests, bs4

При парсинге страниц типа : http://ege.fipi.ru/os11/xmodules/qprint/index.php?theme_guid=3a79f6089541e311b960001fc68344c9&proj_guid=AC437B34557F88EA4115D2F374B0A07B
картинки в html коде отображаются так: ShowPictureQ('docs/AC437B34557F88EA4115D2F374B0A07B/questions/152BBBDB652099E2441838621BF9C867(copy1)/xs3qstsrc152BBBDB652099E2441838621BF9C867_1_1417081012.png')
Как мне получить url картинок с помощью библиотек requests и bs4?
В дальнейшем планирую заменять нынешний вид картинок на <img src 'url'>
возможно есть более простой способ, буду очень благодарен если подскажете его.

Comment: сайт http://ege.fipi.ru/ отвечает You don't have permission to access / on this server... что за секретный ресурс? ;)

Comment: ресурс для подготовки к ЕГЭ)))
попробуйте перейти сначала на этот сайт: https://fipi.ru/ege/otkrytyy-bank-zadaniy-ege#!/tab/173765699-2
а потом открыть ссылку из вопроса

Comment: почитайте про sessions для requests: для парсинга картинок вам понадобятся, скорее всего, кукизы, которые устанавлявает главная страница, потом пробуйте искать в супе `soup.find_all('p', class_='MsoNormal')`

Comment: @Jack_oS, я это всё уже сделал. меня интересует как получить url картинок с помощью кода. и получить их в таком виде как будто бы я нажал "скопировать url картинки"

Comment: ааа... так допишите в начало адрес сайта и получите урл, по которому откроется файл-картинка...

Comment: @Jack_oS, не совсем понял куда и что нужно дописать